# Do the MySQL time_zone* tables get updated automatically on Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

We use a MySQL 2nd Gen 5.7 instance on Google Cloud Platform. I've seen the `mysql.time_zone*` tables already contain timezone information. Will this information be updated automatically when timezones change?

On our baremetal systems we're used to run
`mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -u root mysql`
once a month to keep this information up-to-date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is already [an issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/78686880) regarding that on the Google's issuetracker that you can follow.

As an alternative you could use [Google Time Zone API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/intro).